# What's wrong with this argument for $NP \ne EXP$?

Tags: computer-science, proof-verification, computational-complexity, fake-proofs

Let $\{M_i\}$ be any enumeration of all Turing machines in which each machine appears an infinite number of times.

Consider the language $D = \{i \, | \, M_i(i) \text{ does not accept within }\log(i)^{\log(i)} \text{ steps}\}$.  By standard diagonalization arguments, $D \notin P$.  Clearly, by simulation, $D \in EXP$.

Now, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $D \in NP$ - that is, there is some way to simulate these machines in $NP$.  Consider the related problem $D^{TQBF}$, which is the same language except that $\{M_i\}$ is now an enumeration of Turing machines that can compute relative to $TQBF$ (or any other $PSPACE$-complete problem will do).

Using the same simulation technique, we know that $D^{TQBF} \in NP^{TQBF}$.  Using the same diagonalization argument, $D^{TQBF} \notin P^{TQBF}$.  But $P^{TQBF} = NP^{TQBF}$.  This is a contradiction, so $D \notin NP$.

So $D$ is a problem that is in $EXP$ but not $NP$, so $NP \ne EXP$.

---

What's wrong with this argument?

Comment: Sorry, $x$ was a notational mistake on my part.  To correctly diagonalize, $x$ should have been $\log(i)$ (or length(i), but I'll use $\log$ to be less confusing).  I edited that into my post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in "Using the same simulation technique, we know that $D^{TQBF}\in NP^{TQBF}$". In fact the simulation argument gave you $D\in EXP$ but not directly $D\in NP$ . You have no reason to believe that $D\in NP$ relativises with respect to TQBF.

Comment: That makes sense, I suppose.  It somehow seems overwhelmingly likely to me that $D \in NP$ implies $D^{TQBF} \in NP^{TQBF} = PSPACE$, but I guess I don't know how to rigorously show that.  I wonder if there are any known examples of problem $P$ in complexity class $A$, yet $P^O \notin A^O$.

Comment: It is known that belonging to P or NP does not behave well with oracle, because there is A such that $P^A=NP^A$ and $B$ such that $P^B\neq NP^B$.